# Space needed for Kali-Linux?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, multi-boot

I am curious about how much space to allocate on SSD for Kali-Linux as a second operating system.

I've read requirements ranging between 10 GB and 17 GB. It seems like it would be safest to assume that the OS would need something like 20 GB assuming I am using tools like MetaSploit, Armitage, etc.

I've also read that Kali-Linux enables manual partition installs.

Is there a recommended amount of space I would allocate for Kali-Linux on my eSATA HDD? I have a 128 GB SSD and 1 TB eSATA HDD on my new computer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

After using it for a little while, my installation of Kali Linux is still under 10 GiB. It certainly wouldn't hurt to have more.

The [Kali Linux installation guide](http://docs.kali.org/installation/kali-linux-hard-disk-install) says it requires 10 GB. If you install [every Kali Linux package](https://www.kali.org/news/kali-linux-metapackages/), it would take an extra 15 GB. It looks like 25 GB is a reasonable amount for the system, plus a bit for personal files, so you might go for 30 or 40 GB.

Comment: So you'd say, 20 GB for the system drive (SSD) and an extra 20 GB or so for the HDD?

Comment: Put it all on the eSATA HDD - No need to split between drives

Comment: I guess Kali would boot fast no matter what drive I'd place it on, eh?

Comment: @BenN would I notice anything different if I installed Linux on my eSATA drive instead?

Comment: @KieranOjakangas I doubt you would notice the difference. There's nothing wrong with separation though, storing big chunks of data on the bigger drive.

Comment: @BenN So maybe 10 GB for the OS on SSD and 40 on HDD?

Comment: @KieranOjakangas That would work, but I would probably go for 15 GB, just to be safe.

Comment: @BenN cool man. One other thing. Extra packages, you mean armitage and stuff like that right? And should I use the Ubuntu installer to partition the drives?

Comment: @KieranOjakangas That's a different question. I suggest you do some research, and ask a new question if you don't find anything.

Answer (score 3):

Kali Linux comes with an iso of almost 4 GB which on installation expands to almost 8 GB but if you are using metasploit with armitage then you may also need some swap space then for me 20 GB is for Linux and 1 GB is for swap and it works well without lag also you can use metasploit console and armitage sideways for exporting different frameworks at the same time!